# Add hours in a date in PHP

Tags: php

Want to add hours in a date .
Please help.

The PHP code is:

```
$createdDate=date_create("2013-03-17 07:11:00");
$hour = 4;
```

I tried using strtotime. But it gives an error.

Thanks

Comment: You can use following.

You want to add only 1 hour, There for you have to add 60*60*1 into current date;

    $date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))+3600);
You get my Point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use DateTime modify method.

```
$date = new DateTime("2013-03-17 07:11:00");
$date->modify("+4 hours");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rsXA2a)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval):

```
$iv = new DateInterval("PT{$hour}H");
$createdDate->add($iv);
// $createdDate is now modified
```

Comment: "Have to" is somewhat strong. :)

Comment: -1, Not clear enough , please provide link of the function

Comment: @diEcho Is it too much to assume OP can Google it themselves?

Comment: Is not adding link enough for a downvote ???

Comment: @Baba I didn't think so, but perhaps new rules have emerged ;-)

Comment: + I really don't agree

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
date_modify($createdDate, "+4 hours");
```